# Where and what is the mistake?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 2 green balls and 3 red balls. two balls are drawn at random. Find the probability that the balls  are red and green?

Solution- A there are 2 green balls and 3 red balls, two balls taken from this can be

1. G G
2. G R
3. R G
4. R R

As all the balls are identical

So probability of getting a red and green = 2/4 = 1/2.

I know this is absolutely wrong but someone please explain correctly what is the mistake here. I cant see what is wrong in this.

The correct solution is 2c1 * 3c1 / 5c2 = 3/5

Comment: It's not enough to list the outcomes. You have to consider how many ways each outcome can occur.

Comment: pls explain. in coin problem we do exactly like this right

Comment: There are more red balls than green, so you don't have an equal chance, for example, of drawing GG as you do RR.

Comment: There is only one way to get two green balls but there are three ways to get two red balls, for example.Which is more likely?

Comment: actually probability is favourable outomes/total outcomes ... these 4 are the total outcomes possible( if we are taking all green balls as same instead of g1 and g2). out of that favourable outcomes for us are one red and one green.

Comment: But these four outcomes are not all equally likely. If you take just ONE ball out, there are two possible outcomes; R or G. But there is not a 50% chance of R, because there are different numbers of red and green balls in the bag.

Comment: understood... .

Comment: but even f there are equal red and green balls it does not come like that. why is it that

Answer (score 1):

Re your comment:

"but even if there are equal red and green balls it does not come like that. why is it that"

Firstly, you need to be clear whether the balls are drawn with replacement or without replacement. From the context, they are drawn w/o replacement. Taking two balls of each color, let us work out probabilities directly, and understand why this happens.

$P(RR) = \frac 2 4 \frac 1 3 = \frac 1 6,$
$P(BB) = \frac 2 4 \frac 1 3 = \frac 1 6,$
$P(RB) = \frac 2 4 \frac 2 3 = \frac 1 3,$
$P(BR) = \frac 2 4 \frac 2 3 = \frac 1 3,$

So you can clearly see why the probabilities aren't identical.

The shorter way to compute P(one of each color) is $\frac {^2C_1\cdot^2C_1}{ ^4C_2} = \frac2 3$